# Mongodb | pushing into array inside a specific index of object inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
db.Posts.update({_id: replyTestPostId}, {
    $push: {
       "comments.$[0].replies": replyTestObject
    }
});
```

I want to push inside this replies array inside the comment which is in turn inside another comments array inside a post object

Here is an example data structure -

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e3a0e8647e778cf3c984837"
    },
    "user": {
        "$oid": "5e38e94c5c50fe7afb44866a"
    },
    "timestamp": {
        "$timestamp": {
            "t": 1580863110,
            "i": 1
        }
    },
    "body": "user8's second post",
    "likes": [],
    "comments": [{
        "user": {
            "$oid": "5e38e95a5c50fe7afb44866b"
        },
        "timestamp": {
            "$timestamp": {
                "t": 0,
                "i": 0
            }
        },
        "body": "user9's first comment on friends post",
        "likes": [],
        "replies": []
    }]
}
```

So basically I want to insert an object inside the replies array of that "user9's first comment on friends post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.Posts.update({_id: replyTestPostId}, {
    $push: {
       "comments.0.replies": replyTestObject
    }
});
```

For some reason this wasn't working but now it is. Thank you for anyone who went through the question anyway.